# Decoding the cryptic Emacs mode-line

Tags: mode-line

In my mode-line there's a cryptic set of characters like `-UUU:@%*--F32`

I know I could read through the documentation to figure out what they all mean, but I'd rather just hit a key and have a window pop up with a human-readable expansion of each of those mode-line characters that are showing up in my currently active buffer.

Is there a package that does this?

Comment: Dunno about a package that does that. But see the Elisp manual, node [Mode Line Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html): variables `mode-line-mule-info` (`UUU:@`), `mode-line-modified` (`%*`), and `mode-line-frame-identification` (`--F32`).

Answer (score 2):

Just hold your mouse pointer over the various parts, and read the tooltips.
Maybe it doesn't answer all your questions about the modeline, but most of them at least.

Comment: I only use terminal Emacs, not GUI Emacs, so using the mouse is not an option for me.  Even if it was, I'd like to find a solution that does not require the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but better than nothing:

- First: `M-x ielm` (or `SPC SPC ielm` in spacemacs) to get an "IELM" elisp REPL.
- Then (non-spacemacs): Type `diminished-mode-alist` and hit return (not perfect because some use lisp forms rather than strings)
- Or (spacemacs): Type `spacemacs--diminished-minor-modes` and hit return (this will show the unicode symbols used in the mode line)

Not directly relevant to the question, but you can also use `C-h m` (`describe-mode`) to see more information about currently active modes.

See also: `minor-mode-alist`, `mode-line-format`.